# Why io-throughput of `select *` is faster than `select one colmun` in local disk using parquet-arrow

Tags: sql, io, parquet, apache-arrow, page-caching

I have two sql using parquet-arrow:

```
`table` has 50 column
sql1 = `select * from table`, total_data_size = 45GB
sql2 = `select value from table`, total_data_size = 30GB
```

I add profile for io-throughput(Yeah, drop page-cache and just watch disk-io).

**I found:**

Parquet on HDFS: sql2 is faster than sql1, about 1.5 times which is reasonable

Parquet on local-disk(1MB randread=130MB;1MB read=250MB): sq1 is faster than sql2, about 4 times which is confusing.

**I guess two reasons via `iostat`:**

1. the io-load is high(about 100~130MB/S, utils=90%~100%) when execute sql2, which seem mean the `select one column` is more `rand read` and make the io-throughput decrease
2. `select *` will cache more page-cache and the hit-ratio is high in process though I drop page-cache before executing. so for the `select *`, the io-throughput actually is benefit from cache hit ratio.

Expect your help,  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I use [cachestat](https://github.com/brendangregg/perf-tools/blob/master/fs/cachestat) to get the page-cache hit-ratio, and I found `select *` has higher ratio(50%) than `select one column`(27%), so the io-throughput of `select *` is more better because of the page-cache

I try open with `O_DIRECT` to read the parquet to make sure the conclusion, but it report `errno: 22, strerror: Invalid argument`, I haven't found the error root cause, but I think the page-cache hit-ratio is the root cause for io-throughput.

However, why `select *` has higher hit-ratio?

Comment: This answer would be better as an edit to your question because it doesn't actually answer the question, but just explains more of what you did to try to solve it.